# Why did the total blocking time increase from one test to another, in pageSpeed Insights?

Tags: php, html, seo

I have the following situation.
In an online store that I manage and whose programmer I am, I made the following change. In the shopping cart, when there are products in the cart, immediately after listing the products, similar to a product, I add another section where the cost regarding the transport is displayed. Simple php and html code. No other previous processing is done, having already established the information.
Before putting the changes into production, I did a check in PageSpeed insights (pagespeed.web.dev), receiving the following values on the Mobile version:

First Contentful Paint: 2.8 s
Speed Index: 3.6 s
Largest Contentful Paint: 3.7 s
Time to Interactive: 6.0 s
Total Blocking Time: 200 ms
Cumulative Layout Shift: 0.001

Afterwards, I uploaded the modification to production and repeated the test obtaining the following values on the Mobile version:
First Contentful Paint 2.8 s
Speed Index 2.9 s
Largest Contentful Paint 3.1 s
Time to Interactive 6.0 s
Total Blocking Time 290 ms
Cumulative Layout Shift 0.001

Between the 2 tests I noticed that certain values are lower, but one increased, Total Blocking Time from 200 to 290.

I mention the fact that both tests are done without having products in the shopping cart. Which would mean that the added code portion is not displayed on the page when the tests are performed.

Why does this increase occur from one test to another? If no other changes were made to the site?
At the same time, doing several tests in PageSpeed insights, on the same page, a few seconds apart, without making changes to the page, certain indicators such as Speed Index, Largest Contentful Paint, Time to Interactive, Total Blocking Time, change from one test to another, they do not remain constant. Can you explain why?

Thank you!

Before putting the changes into production, I did a check in PageSpeed insights (pagespeed.web.dev), receiving the following values on the Mobile version:

First Contentful Paint: 2.8 s
Speed Index: 3.6 s
Largest Contentful Paint: 3.7 s
Time to Interactive: 6.0 s
Total Blocking Time: 200 ms
Cumulative Layout Shift: 0.001

Afterwards, I uploaded the modification to production and repeated the test obtaining the following values on the Mobile version:
First Contentful Paint 2.8 s
Speed Index 2.9 s
Largest Contentful Paint 3.1 s
Time to Interactive 6.0 s
Total Blocking Time 290 ms
Cumulative Layout Shift 0.001

Between the 2 tests I noticed that certain values are lower, but one increased, Total Blocking Time from 200 to 290.

Answer (score 0):

If there have been changes to the server that is hosting the page, such as an increase in traffic or a change in server configuration, it could be affecting the total blocking time.

Please refer this link https://web.dev/tbt/

It may help you.